# Codeblocks and CppUTest, undefined reference

Tags: c++, tdd, codeblocks, cpputest

I am trying to compile the following test application using CodeBlocks and CppUTest, however no matter what I do I always get the `undefined reference` error. I compiled CppUTest with cygwin, in codeblocks I use MinGW.

The project directory just has two files, `main.cpp` and `tests.cpp`, I am trying to get this to compile.

This is the `main.cpp` file:

```
#include "CppUTest/CommandLineTestRunner.h"
int main(int ac, char** av)
{
   return CommandLineTestRunner::RunAllTests(ac, av);
}
```

This is the `tests.cpp` file:

```
#include "CppUTest/TestHarness.h"
TEST_GROUP(FirstTestGroup)
{
};

TEST(FirstTestGroup, FirstTest)
{
   FAIL("Fail me!");
}
TEST(FirstTestGroup, SecondTest)
{
   STRCMP_EQUAL("hello", "world");
   LONGS_EQUAL(1, 2);
   CHECK(false);
}
```

I already have the libraries `libCppUTest.a` and `libCppUTestExt.a`, now I have to link them to the project. For this I've attempted the following:

- In build options, add `<CppUTest>\include\` to search directories for the compiler.
- In build options, add `<CppUTest>\lib\` to search directories for the linker.
- In link settings, add `libCppUTest.a` and `libCppUTestExt.a` to link libraries. Also tried with the full path to these libraries.

I think the problem is not Codeblocks, because I've tried with every guide I've found to link the libraries and I always get `undefined reference`. I've also tried to add these as global settings but I get the same error, `undefined reference`.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is no C code. Do not add C tag for C++.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Apologies.

Comment: Libraries in C++ have no standard format and are not inter-operable even with different compiler versions. I'm suspecting it's because of the different compilers. Read about name mangling in C++ shared libraries.

Comment: can't you use Cmake on windows to compile it? and can't you use DLL libraries?

Comment: I tried to use Cmake GUI and MinGW make, however CppUTest 3.7.1 (latest version) doesn't build with MinGW due to an issue of this compiler with pthreads. So I used cygwin to compile it.

Comment: @Sreekar you were right, I changed the compiler settings in Codeblocks to cygwin and after fixing the paths finally I got it to work. Yes!

Comment: @Mite glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Sreekar, the problem is that I was using MinGW in codeblocks and the libraries were compiled with cygwin. Changing the compiler to cygwin in Codeblocks fixed the issue for me.

This describes the process to change the compiler to cygwin in codeblocks if needed:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVmd0P85D8o